# Prove that $BD=DC$.

Tags: geometry, area

**While solving a question paper of** **RMO-$2014$** **The only problem I cannot solve was:**

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $AD$ be the perpendicular from $A$ on $BC.$

Let $K,L,M$ be points on $AD$ such that $AK=KL=LM=MD$. Segments parallel to $BC$ are drawn through $K,L,M$ as shown in figure. If the sum of the areas of the shaded regions is equals to the sum of the areas of the unshaded regions,prove that $BD=DC.$
[image: This is the figure given]

Please help me to solve this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your *question*, though?

Comment: ^And what have you done so far ?

Comment: I think you must read the topic first

Comment: Hint: areas of triangles with a common altitude are in the same ratio as their respective bases. For example $S_{ABD} / S_{ADC}= BD / DC$.

Comment: I tried this by assuming that $BD=DC$  and then tried to show that the areas are equal by using the area of trapeziums formed but I get trapped when I reach the triangles above

Comment: You can't assume the conclusion you are trying to prove. You *could* try to assume that $BD \lt DC$, for example, then derive a contradiction, though that's not the most direct way.

Comment: @dvix. Actually I changed the question for me that If $BD=DC$ then show that areas are equal

Comment: @Justin Bieber if $BD = DC$ then $AD $ will be the median of the triangle. Now since all those 3 lines are parallel to the base then all those 4 triangle are similar. Now I think the is already half solved. Do you want me to post the solution or you will try? I recommend you to post the original question.

Comment: I will try your hint is appreciable

Comment: If one knows from the beginning that $BD=DC$ then the problem becomes too simple for the RMO level.